# How do I pad two sentences into same shape with tf.data.Dataset.padded_batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I want to build a seq2seq model and I build a tensorflow dataset with {source, target} pair.
When I tried to pad these two vectors I found that I can't pad them into same shape

```
batched_train = dataset_train.padded_batch(32,padded_shapes={
   "source":tf.TensorShape([None]),
   "target":tf.TensorShape([None])}, drop_remainder=True)
batched_val = dataset_val.padded_batch(32,padded_shapes={
   "source":tf.TensorShape([None]),
   "target":tf.TensorShape([None])}, drop_remainder=True)
```

And I get the shape of source is (32, 107), and the shape of target is (32, 180), I'm wandering how can I fix this.

Comment: I manually set None to a specific number like 200, and it can work. But I'm wandering whether there is a more robust way to do this.